# Downloading PyTorch datasets gives a "raw" folder

Tags: pytorch, dataset, torchvision

I'm using PyTorch trying to download the FashionMNIST dataset from the torchvision.datasets module. The download works fine but instead of downloading a train and test folder I end up with a "raw" folder that has some ubyte.gz files inside.

Has anyone come cross this problem or has any idea how to solve it?
I managed to download the datasets and get them to work properly a couple of days ago. This ended up happening recently and I couldn't find any solution online.
Thank you in advance!